# Медленная скорость закачки на сервере

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

На сервер возникла проблема *CentOS 7*:

Скорость загрузки файлов на сервер не превышает 50-70 Кб/cек, при этом скорость скачивания с сервера хорошая (1 Мб - 1.5 Мб).

Думал возможно проблема с *ftp*. Менял параметры в конфиге *vsftpd* (*local_max_rate*). Также пробовал в разных режимах передачи (пассивный и активный).

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Вы другие протоколы пробовали? попробуйте утилитой iperf  замерить скорость

Comment: И если проблема в `ftp`, добавь в вопрос конфиг.